# Extjs-4 store of itemselector

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have store load of itemselector from Json or database now i am inserted another value in Json or database now I want to reload store so please tell me how I can reload store of itemselector.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
store.load();
```

Best I can do as you've not posted any code.